# LOAD LOCAL XML INFILE runs without errors, but nothing loads

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load and XML file into a mysql table, without success. I've shrunk the db table down to a single row single column (there are more columns in the table) xml file to test this.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE  '/home/acct/public_html/db_files/data.xml' INTO TABLE db.table ROWS IDENTIFED BY '<DATA_ROW>'
```

The entire XML file I am trying to load

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="DATA.xsd" generated="2018-04-26T13:52:35">
<DATA_ROW>
<NUMBER>414930440570</NUMBER>
<NAME_1>John Doe</NAME_1>
</DATA_ROW>
</dataroot>
```

When I run the LOAD XMLLOCAL INFILE command above it appears to run without error, but nothing loads into the table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo it must be `IDENTIFIED`

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE  '/home/acct/public_html/db_files/data.xml' 
INTO TABLE db.table1 
ROWS IDENTIFIED  BY '<DATA_ROW>'
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I looked over that so many times. I had an idea it would be something right in front of me. Thank you for the quick response.